# Parsing date strings, inferring the year such that the date is not in the future

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, datetime, error-handling

I got this program that I am working on and in it, I got a section that has a try statement and two error except statements.

```
try:
    ...
    if ...: raise SyntaxError
except SyntaxError:
    ...
except ValueError:
    ...
```

The thing is that the SyntaxErrors are technically ValueErrors, but the errors occur for different reasons, therefore need different code to solve/get around the problem. So in order to prevent the code in all the "excepts" from being executed, I had to separate/make the type of Errors different. Is it okay to do that even though the SyntaxErrors are techincally ValueErrors, that I label them as SyntaxErrors? Or is there a method in solving this problem?

Here is the code of the program:

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime(2019, 1, 1).date() 
this_year = 2019
last_year = this_year - 1

text = ["Dec 31 ", "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Dec 31 "]

for line in text:
    date_str = line
    try:
        date = datetime.strptime(date_str + str(this_year), "%b %d %Y").date()
        if date > today: raise SyntaxError
        print("+", date)
    except SyntaxError:
        date = datetime.strptime(date_str + str(last_year), "%b %d %Y").date()
        print("-", date)
    except ValueError:
        print("abnormality")
        continue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtaining a date that is in the future is in no way a "syntax error", and it would be inappropriate to raise a `SyntaxError`.  Instead of abusing the exception-handling mechanism, you should just use a conditional.

```
for date_str in text:
    try:
        date = datetime.strptime(date_str + str(this_year), "%b %d %Y").date()
        if date <= today:
            print("+", date)
        else:
            date = datetime.strptime(date_str + str(last_year), "%b %d %Y").date()
            print("-", date)
    except ValueError:
        print("abnormality")
```

Note that you might be misinterpreting some `ValueError`s as abnormalities.  For example, `"Feb 29 2021"` would cause a `ValueError`, but then you would never get a chance to try `"Feb 29 2020"`, which is a valid day in a leap year.

Comment: Ok thank you. But if the current date is Feb 29 2021, there would be no point in look at Feb 29 2020 since it is a year behind.

Comment: I think you thought that the program is supposed to look into future dates/year. But it is not supposed to do that. It looks at the past, in a sense. It moves the year backwards, but keeps the months and days the same. This is to prevent the variable “date” from equaling “Dec 31 2020” if Ithe current date is “Jan 1 2020”. The reason for that dives into a much bigger program. The current program that I posted was a small snippet that could work independently from the actual program it was apart of.

Comment: Your _goal_ may be to ensure that `date` is in the past. However, your _implementation_ works by initially attempting to parse the date in the `this_year` calendar year, which may trigger an unintended `ValueError` before you even get a chance to do the `if date > today` test.

Comment: But a ValueError shouldn’t even come up because if I am looking at this years calendar and if there a a valid leap year, or if there is not, it will follow the rule of the calendar.

Comment: It shouldn’t say Feb 29 if on this years calendar there is no Feb 29 since the program goes by this years calendar.

Comment: If you execute the program with `today = datetime(2021, 1,1).date()`, `this_year = 2021`, and `text = ["Feb 29 "]`, what do you intend for your program's output to be, and why?

Comment: Ok. I see, I am being really narrow minded. I am thinking from the perspective of the bigger program that this snippet of code is from. The bigger code automatically goes by the current calendar which in term would preventing a ValueError from appearing. It does it by grabbing dates from a log file that only keeps up to 7 days worth of logs. So I understand what your saying. Sorry that I didn’t get it right away.

Answer (score 0):

just a note on syntax error. a syntax error occurs when you have a fault with your writing of python, not with your logic or values. if the lexer goes through your program and finds if x == 3 ::, it will raise a syntax error as it finds an unexpected :. but 3 + 'm' is not of this type as the lexer finds nothing wrong in it.